# Need alternative to dropdown in each cell

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, dropdown, alternatives

In each cell I want to show a dropdown which contains values such as 1,2,3... up to 10. But as you can see, if I show a dropdown then the page will be full of dropdowns (As there are 288 cells) and I don't know if all the dropdowns will fit in a page or not.

Do you have any better idea for this kind of layouts?

[image: Need alternative to dropdown in each cell]

Comment: User can also just enter the number himself inside the cell.. Will that work for you?

Comment: No this will not work as I want to restrict user to enter only a list of values.

Comment: Are the options in the dropdown the same for each cell?

Comment: Yes they are same in each cell

Answer (score 1):

[image: Dropdown view]

One Suggestion: Have the three dots icon in the top row having numbers (0-23) and in that drop down the option of days should be shown so accordingly user will select one or multiple options.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be having your values in a box (To the right or above of the data set or even floating maybe?) that changes according to where the user have clicked.

The visual changes of the values should be sufficient enough for the user to quickly learn that it is the input method. Along with some information text could be a solution.